# Arredondamentos para cima

Tags: python, csv

Eu tenho a seguinte lista de dicionários e as values correspondem ao valor de média , por exemplo , no 1º aparece 4 , mas na verdade da 4,6666. Gostava de saber como e que se arrendonda , já tentei com o round , mas fica igual.

```
[{'Nome do Dono': 'Eva', 'Media de Idade': 4}, {'Nome do Dono': 'Ana', 'Media de Idade': 53}, {'Nome do Dono': 'Ada', 'Media de Idade': 12}]
```

Comment: Pode ser mais específico(a) a respeito do problema? Como sabe que não está funcionando? Recebe um erro? Se sim, cole a mensagem de erro aqui. Recebe uma saída inesperada? Se sim, coloque a saída esperada e a saída recebida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import math
valor = 4.6666
valor_arredondado = math.ceil(valor)
print valor_arredondado # 5.0
```